# What is the lowest version of Visual Studio 2010 that supports Database Projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, database-project

i just wanted to get a final answer, as i'm not 100% sure.

what versions of Visual Studio 2010 contain the database projects?

I only own the premium and ultimate versions, and don't know anyone who has pro to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [product comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison) it is only premium and ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like pro may not have it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/0ccd8061-83b0-40c6-9aa7-b6275abb53b8/